# GoogleNet fails to classify images

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I built Keras Google Net from here:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/10/understanding-inception-network-from-scratch/
The only difference is that I replaced 1000 classes in output layers with 3.  data is prepared this way :

```
def grey_preprocessor (xarray):
    xarray=(xarray/127.5)-1
    return xarray

img_resol = (224,224)
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip = True, preprocessing_function = grey_preprocessor).flow_from_directory(
    directory = train_path, target_size=img_resol, classes = ['bacterial', 'healthy', 'viral'], batch_size = 10)
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip = True, preprocessing_function = grey_preprocessor).flow_from_directory(
    directory = valid_path, target_size=img_resol, classes = ['bacterial', 'healthy', 'viral'], batch_size = 10)
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip = True, preprocessing_function = grey_preprocessor).flow_from_directory(
    directory = test_path, target_size=img_resol, classes = ['bacterial', 'healthy', 'viral'], batch_size = 10, shuffle = False)

assert train_batches.n == 4222
assert valid_batches.n == 300
assert test_batches.n == 150
assert train_batches.num_classes == valid_batches.num_classes == test_batches.num_classes == 3
```

I train it like this:
`history = model.fit(train_batches, validation_data=valid_batches, epochs=epochs, batch_size=256, callbacks=[lr_sc])`

However, all the accuracies on every batch are 0.3333, which means it doesn't classify at all. I understand that it can be anything. What is a good way to troubleshoot it?

Comment: could you tell what do you have as `xarray`.(I mean which type of images)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to normalize your grayscale image use this!

```py
def gray_preprocessor (xarray):
    xarray=xarray/255.0
    return xarray
```

or you can also use lambda function:

```
gray_preprocessor = lambda xarray : xarray / 255.0
```

Comment: It's a pneumonia dataset from kaggle.
https://www.kaggle.com/kostasdiamantaras/chest-xrays-bacterial-viral-pneumonia-normal?select=labels_train.csv

It works perfectly fine with VGG16. I did the same trick there dense layer with 3 outputs instead of 1000.
 
also here is how I train googlenet:
```
history = model.fit(train_batches, validation_data=valid_batches, epochs=epochs, batch_size=256, callbacks=[lr_sc])
```